# How to uninstall emailmail server?

Tags: debian, email-server, uninstall

Mail was accidentally installed on my debian server and I want to remove all mta, mail related software. I do not know what exactly was installed, how can I find out and uninstall this stuff? I don't want to see this "you have mail" when I log in.

Answer (score 3):

Check which daemon is active on port 25:

```
sudo lsof -i :25 


> COMMAND PID        USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
> exim4   944 Debian-exim    3u  IPv4  19380      0t0  TCP localhost:smtp (LISTEN)
> exim4   944 Debian-exim    4u  IPv6  19381      0t0  TCP localhost:smtp (LISTEN)
```

now, you have to remove **exim4** service:

```
sudo apt-get remove exim4-base
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

or

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

for a shorter list, which shows you what is installed.  Look through the list, work out the major packages you don't need (like exim, postfix, mailx, bsd-mailx, etc.) and then,

```
apt-get remove exim mailx ......
```

Comment: Do you see any mail related packages in this list? https://gist.github.com/2889285

Comment: I still get "You have mail" :-(

Comment: That's probably because you have content in `/var/spool/mail/userid`.  If you don't care about mail, just delete your file from there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using postfix since it's the default mail server for Debian (I think).  You should be able to remove this by using:

```
apt-get remove postfix
```

If it's not the postfix package just substitute the name of the package that was installed.

Comment: My bad, postfix is the mail server, sub mutt for postfix (is the default mail client on most of the distro's I  have seen).